# How to perform the equivalent of Excel countifs with multiple conditions in dplyr?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, dplyr, countif

In the below reproducible code, I would like to add a column for `CountIfs` as detailed in the below image, whereby the Excel `countifs()` formula in the image has multiple conditions with the tops of the specified ranges "anchored". Any recommendations for how to do the same in dplyr? I'm sure it requires grouping but unsure of how to handle the multiple conditions. The blue below shows the current reproducible code output, the yellow shows what I would like to add, and the non-highlighted shows the underlying `countifs()` formula.

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

myData <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("R","R","T","R","N","N","T"),
    Group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0),
    Code = c(0,2,2,0,3,0,4)
  )

myDataRender <- myData %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(CodeGrp = if_else(Group == 0, 0, max(Code)))
print.data.frame(myDataRender)
```

**Posting alternative dataframe and Excel countifs() example:**

```
> myData1
   Name Group Code1 Code2
1     B     0     0     0
2     R     1     1     0
3     R     1     1     1
4     R     2     3     0
5     R     2     3     1
6     B     0     0     0
7     A     3     1     0
8     A     3     1     1
9     A     0     0     0
10    A     0     0     0
11    A     0     0     0

myData1 <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("B","R","R","R","R","B","A","A","A","A","A"),
    Group = c(0,1,1,2,2,0,3,3,0,0,0),
    Code1 = c(0,1,1,3,3,0,1,1,0,0,0),
    Code2 = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)
  )
```

Desired output rendered in XLS:

[image]

**Small change to Rui Barrada's solution to make his for-loop code exactly reflect the `COUNTIFS()` formula in the XLS example:**

```
fun_aux <- function(x,y) {
  out <- integer(length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    cond1 <- y[1:i] > 0
    cond2 <- x[1:i] == x[i] # the y in this line in Rui's code is changed to x (for x[i]) to correspond with XLS countifs() example
    out[i] <- sum(cond1*cond2)
  }
  out
}
```

**Equivalent of above for-loop function using base **sapply()**:**

```
mutate(CountIfs = sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Code2[1:x] > 0 & Code1[1:x] == Code1[x])))
```

Comment: Check out case_when https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.
Vectorized code like what `dplyr` or the `tidyverse` uses is not suited for rolling functions, where the current result depends on the previous ones. So I have written an auxiliary function `fun_aux` to take care of computing the expected result.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

myData1 <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("B","R","R","R","R","B","A","A","A","A","A"),
    Group = c(0,1,1,2,2,0,3,3,0,0,0),
    Code1 = c(0,1,1,3,3,0,1,1,0,0,0),
    Code2 = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)
  )

fun_aux <- function(x, y) {
  out <- integer(length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    cond1 <- y[1:i] > 0
    cond2 <- x[1:i] == y[i]
    out[i] <- sum(cond1*cond2)
  }
  out
}

myDataRender <- myData1 %>% 
  mutate(CountIfs = fun_aux(Code1, Code2))

print.data.frame(myDataRender)
#>    Name Group Code1 Code2 CountIfs
#> 1     B     0     0     0        0
#> 2     R     1     1     0        0
#> 3     R     1     1     1        1
#> 4     R     2     3     0        0
#> 5     R     2     3     1        1
#> 6     B     0     0     0        0
#> 7     A     3     1     0        0
#> 8     A     3     1     1        2
#> 9     A     0     0     0        0
#> 10    A     0     0     0        0
#> 11    A     0     0     0        0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Rui, I tried the above and it didn't generalize for my broader application. I still don't really understand how to run the equivalent of XLS countifs(multiple conditions) via dplyr. Could you please take a look at the additional, simpler example I added to the OP? I shouldn't have even included the ´Groups´ column in the new dataframe because it's not relevant to the countifs().

Comment: @Village.Idyot I don't understand the new data. In rows 5 and 8, both Codes are equal to 1 but countif is 1 in row 5 and 2 in row 8 . Why? Can you explain in words the logic of the computations?

Comment: Hi Rudy, apologies for the lack of clarity. I tried explaining in words in my TarJae comments.

Comment: @Village.Idyot Done, see the code now.

Comment: Wow! And that code is very understandable. Btw are you based in Lisbon? On Linked In I see two Rui Barradas in Lisbon

Comment: @Village.IdyotYes, I live in Lisbon but none of those is me.

Comment: OK I got warned about extended discussions but here goes, last summer we were in Porto and then the Rio Douro area. We loved it! Want to go to Nazaré soon with my son to see giant wave surfers and enroll in surf camp. Obrigado!

Comment: One last note: I edited the OP to reflect the solution with one small change to make the solution 100% reflect the XLS ´countifs()´ example

Comment: @Village.Idyot OK, thanks, I had missed that point. (And it's Rui, without a *d*.)

Comment: Ahh I've been working a lot with a Rui, on something else!